# Python: Read a file and turn it into a dictionary with first+second line being the key

Tags: python, file, dictionary, file-read

I'm trying to read a file that look something like this:

```
Lee
Louise
12345678
711-2880 Nulla St. Mississippi
Chapman
Eric
27681673
Ap 867-859 Sit Rd. New york
(...)
```

and make it into a dictionary with the last and firstname as keys and with the values being lastname, firstname, tel and address. It should look someting like this:

```
{'Lee Louise': ['Lee','Louise','12345678','711-2880 Nulla St. Mississippi'],'Chapman Eric': ['Chapman','Eric','27681673','Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. New york']}
```

And this is what I've done so far:

```
d = dict()
fr = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
info = [k.split('\n') for k in fr]
for k in range(len(info)):
    if k % 4 == 0:
        list = info[k :k + 4]
        new_list = [b[0] for b in list]
        d[info[k][0]] = new_list
return d
```

I only managed to make the lastnames into keys..
What can I do to make both last and firstname into keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code

- You are overriding Python function *list*- bad idea.
- You are already reading lines - use *strip('\n')*, *split* creates parasitic list.
- Use *range* with step 4
- Did I mention 1-letter variable names?

I would re-write fragment of your code as

```
info = open(...).read().splitlines()  # Saves from re-building list
for offset in range(0, len(info), 4):
    d[' '.join(info[offset: offset + 2]) = info[offset: offset + 4]
```

No parasitic list - saving from *new_list* mess

Answer (score 0):

replace `d[info[k][0]] = new_list`

with:

`d[" ".join([info[k][0],info[k][1]]]) = new_list`

Comment: Join requires single positional argument - list or tuple of strings. This will not work. And slice will be more elegant anyway

Comment: I did that and it says TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given), what should I do?

Comment: sorry, like volcano said need to add brackets or parens around the list of the items to join- edited to show that. he also suggested something like d[" ".join(info[k][0:2])] = new_list